# Connection timed out error in JMeter test execution

Tags: http, jmeter, connection-timeout

When am running my **JMeter scripts using GUI** for few of the samples sometimes am getting `Connection timed out` **error** and response are not getting, but if I run the same test after few mins I got the response for the same samples.

Can anybody please answer what is the solution for this?

Currently am checking the response time of each page, if **add timers** than the **page response** time will be showing more right?

Comment: It can be a network issue.

Comment: You can observe system resources (CPU/RAM/Network) on JMeter machine as well as Target Server machine to trace where the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 possibles reasons:

- Your server (meaning web servers handling request and any components after them) is not handling the load correctly and slowing down, monitor the system and check
- You have exhausted your injector ephemeral ports , you need to adjust your OS TCP settings to increase port range
- You're running load test in GUI mode with a View Results Tree in test, this is bad practice as GC will happen frequently possibly triggering Stop The World leading to this. As per best-practices use NON GUI mode:

  - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
  - https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/