# JMeter Test Result - Connect time is 100% of request (HTTP) sample time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jmeter

I am using JMeter 5.1 to conduct performance testing (HTTP requests), the system tested is web application on Google Cloud Platform. For JMeter, I configured 10 threads(users), and got error messages for failed request: **failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)**
and check result in "View Results in Table" found Connect time = Sample time and there is no latency time.

Under this condition, What should I try to find the root cause. Is there any analyze direction or method?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093346/connection-timed-out-error-in-jmeter-test-execution) it explain some causes related to your issue.

In addition, if you are using GCP HTTP(S) Load balancer, you should take a look to stackdriver [logs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#viewing_logs).  That will provide more clues for your issue. You may need to change the [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#timeouts_and_retries) values for your load balancer or your backend.

Comment: Hi Gustavo Blanco, firstly thank you for you updates. I cannot find clues in "Cloud HTTP Load Balancer"  type log.

Comment: Hi.  you should be getting some 502  responses. However please make sure your load balancer is kind HTTP(S) (L7). If your load balancer is L4 (Network load balancer) you will not get stackdriver logs for HTTP responses.
At this point I highly recommend to submit a consult with GCP support team.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo Blanco. Actually I am new to GCP platform, and today I found under loadbalancing, there are two backend service, but  one of them having "NO_BACKEND_SELECTED" metrics data. I guess there are errors for this backend service, and file tickets to devops team just now.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [TCP connection timeout](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-TCP-connection-timeout), if JMeter fails to get the response within the bounds of the [TCP Handshake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transmission_Control_Protocol_(TCP)) it will fail the associated HTTP Request sampler.

Latency (also known as [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte)) would be 0 because there is no any response from the server.

[image]

same for sent bytes, same for header size in bytes.

If for your application response times over 2 minutes is acceptable and expected you can increase Connect timeout, the relevant setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

For example this is how you can increase the Connect timeout to 5 minutes:

[image]

With regards to root cause, the reasons are numerous, i.e.:

- wrong protocol/port combination
- the port is blocked by [OS firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) or [GCP firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)
- the application or VM is overloaded and cannot respont
- incorrect configuration of application server/database/other middleware
- etc.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T , I am sorry to reply late. Recently, I conduct another round of perf testing and along with also did curl test for API host connecting testing. I found normally the established TCP connection time is xx ms, but there is 10%-20% rate , that time can reach 30-60 seconds under performance testing. So it should be the network unstalbe issue, right? Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!